# Can Elasticsearch version 5.5.3 run on Kubernetes with StatefulSet?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've been trying to get Elasticsearch running on K8s using the [newly-promoted-to-stable helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/elasticsearch), which works fine, BTW, for elasticsearch v 6.4.2.  However, we're tied to a grails app that requires elasticsearch v 5.5.3, for which we don't have the ability to upgrade.  I've downgraded the elasticsearch image version in the chart to 5.5.3 (and also tried v 5.6.12) but it fails to start.

I looked into the [elasticsearch operator](https://github.com/upmc-enterprises/elasticsearch-operator), but it's currently set up to work with AWS S3 storage types, out of the box, and GCP with a little work (although no snapshot ability).  Before I dive into this, I'd like to know if it will work with 5.5.3, to begin with.

Does anyone know if I can get elasticsearch v 5.5.3 running in a k8s cluster?  I would say using a k8s StatefulSet at a minimum.

Thanks!

**Update**

I suppose I should have given the errors that the existing helm chart is having when downgrading elasticsearch image to 5.5.3.

master-0 pod fails to start with:

`Error injecting constructor, ElasticsearchException[java.io.IOException: failed to read [id:15, legacy:false, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/_state/global-15.st]]; nested: IOException[failed to read [id:15, legacy:false, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/_state/global-15.st]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Unknown license version found, please upgrade all nodes to the latest elasticsearch-license plugin];
  at org.elasticsearch.gateway.GatewayMetaState.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.elasticsearch.gateway.GatewayMetaState
    for parameter 4 at org.elasticsearch.gateway.GatewayService.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.elasticsearch.gateway.GatewayService
Caused by: ElasticsearchException[java.io.IOException: failed to read [id:15, legacy:false, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/_state/global-15.st]]; nested: IOException[failed to read [id:15, legacy:false, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/_state/global-15.st]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Unknown license version found, please upgrade all nodes to the latest elasticsearch-license plugin];`

The client pods fail with:

`[2018-10-22T17:52:51,835][WARN ][o.e.d.z.UnicastZenPing   ] [elasticsearch-client-6bf954c595-7zlpc] failed to resolve host [elasticsearch-discovery]
java.net.UnknownHostException: elasticsearch-discovery`

Clearly, it's expecting a later elasticsearch version.

Comment: back port the helm chart to version 5.5.3

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @ljaz-Khan?  There is no helm chart for that version of elasticsearch.  And, as I said, when I change the elasticsearch image version to 5.5.3, if fails to start -- the {elasticsearch-discovery} fails to start and {Unknown license version found, please upgrade all nodes to the latest elasticsearch-license plugin}.  I was wondering if someone knew of other changes to the helm chart that might work.  Long shot, I know.  Thanks.

Comment: FYI, I was looking into the history of helm chart to see if there was any point where it supported v5.5.3. It looks like there moved from v5.4 to v6.6.1 [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/commit/12edda76afa45b5b07338372ead46aecf29780b8#diff-5999dc529bb8a6cc5eb520fa1e224200)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer here is that ElasticSearch 5.5.3 should work with Kubernetes. Note the configs for 5.5.3 are slightly different, I believe they changed after 5.6 where for example the made [x-pack](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/xpack-introduction.html) enabled by default, and yes use a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) or start from the existing stable Helm chart.

Comment: Thanks @rico but I guess I was looking for the (hopefully slightly) longer answer -- as in how.

Comment: The how takes time and work since there are no official charts and the operator is for AWS :-)

Answer (score 0):

We ended up going with a variation of [this Medium post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/a-guide-to-deploy-elasticsearch-cluster-on-google-kubernetes-engine-52f67743ee98) to get ES 5.5.3 working in "multi-node" mode. This is not HA in the way the latest ES chart version provides but will get us on our way.

We used a regular storage class, instead of the SSD and we had to disable ES boot checking, for now, because we couldn't get the `ulimit` command to work on ES init.

We have multiple ES nodes and are good until we can upgrade the app to use ES latest version.